# How to correct multi-character error in C?

Tags: c

Here is what I have tried:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int count=0;
    int x;
    char Grade;
    char studentName[50];
    int studentID=0;
    int f=0;

    do
    {
        printf("\nEnter student ID: ");
        scanf("%d", &studentID);

        if(studentID!=0)
        {           
            printf("Enter student name: ");
            scanf("%s", &studentName);
            printf("Enter student marks: ");
            scanf("%d", &x);

            if(x<=100 && x>=80)
                Grade = 'A';
            else if(x<=79 && x>=75)
                Grade = 'A-';
            else if(x<=74 && x>=70)
                Grade = 'B+';
            else if(x<=69 && x>=65)
                Grade = 'B';
            else if(x<=64 && x>=60)
                Grade = 'B-';
            else if(x<=59 && x>=55)
                Grade = 'C+';
            else if(x<=54 && x>=50)
                Grade = 'C';
            else if(x<=49 && x>=45)
                Grade = 'C-';
            else if(x<=44 && x>=40)
                Grade = 'D+';
            else if(x<=39 && x>=35)
                Grade = 'D';
            else if(x<=34 && x>=30)
                Grade = 'D-';
            else if(x<=29 && x>=0)
            {
                Grade = 'F'; 
                f++;
            }   
            printf("%s have the following marks %d and the Grade is %c\n ", studentName, x, Grade);
            count++;        
        }   
    }while(studentID!=0);

    printf("Sum of student =  %d\n", count);
    printf("Sum of fail student = %d\n", f);
}
```

I get the following error when trying to compile:

`"[Warning] multi-character character constant [-Wmultichar]".`

I can execute the code but the error keeps bothering me. Also I cannot get the result which have - Grade.

Please advice as I am new learner. Thanks.

Comment: char can hold one byte. but here Grade = 'B-'; two bytes are assigned.

Comment: Since you're trying to store more than one character in `Grade` it should probably be a string. (Or an enum might make more sense.)

Comment: Given that you need to store two characters, you should probably use `char *Grade;` and then assignments like `Grade = "A-";` with double quotes for a string instead of single quotes, and use `%s` instead of `%c` to print the grade.

Comment: Change `char Grade` to `char* Grade` and all those single quotes to double quotes (for example, change `Grade = 'A'` to `Grade = "A"`).

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out the error is that you are trying to force 2 `char` into a variable that can only contain 1, and this is why you cannot have grades with "-", and I guess you don't have those with the "+" neither : it seems that, in your case (cf @mafso comment), the program only takes the 1st `char` (the letter), the rest is lost.

Let the compiler adjust the size of your containers for you:

```
// With "[]", the compiler will reserve just what we need
const char * grades[] = 
{
    "F", "D-", "D", "D+", "C-", /* etc... */ "A-", "A+"
};
```

Also, I think we can do a little mathematical trick to get directly the string-grade from the rating and avoid "waterfall" `else if`:

```
size_t index;

if(x < 25)    // Safety measure
{
    index = 0; // F
}
else if (x > 79) // [edit] ok we need another one
{
    index = 11; // A (or should it be A+ ?)
}
else // The real trick
{
    index = (x/5 + 1) - 6 ;
}

// You need 3 chars: one for the letter, one for the + (or -) and the
// last one for the NULL-terminating '\0' which is the "end-of-string" byte
char student_grade[3];
strcpy(student_grade, grades[index]);
```

And now you understand why I started `grades` from `"F-"` to `"A"` :)

Comment: "the program only takes the 1st char (the letter), the rest is lost." -- what happens to multi-character constants is implementation-defined. For example, with `gcc`, `'xy'` is `(unsigned char)'x' * 256 + (unsigned char)'y'` (IIRC, `CHAR_BIT` is 8 for all `gcc` targets).

Answer (score 1):

The error is quite indicative of what is wrong with your code. A multi-character character constant indicates you are trying to assign more than one character to a character constant which is wrong. As pointed by mahendiran.b you cannot assign "A-" or "B-" to Grade as it takes only a single character. It should be a string.